# opengl drivers broken, glxgears won't run

Tags: nvidia, opengl

When I try to run glxgears or ssh to a machine and use OpenGL with the -X flag, I get this error message:

```
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Error: couldn't get an RGB, Double-buffered visual
```

The output of lspci is:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev b4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b4)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev b4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM67 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF119 [GeForce GT 520M] (rev a1)
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet (rev c0)
08:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6230 (rev 34)
09:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5116 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
09:00.1 SD Host controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5116 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
0f:00.0 USB controller: Texas Instruments Device 8241 (rev 02)
```

This is a fresh install of ubuntu, and strangely the proprietary NVIDIA driver is not listed under Additional Drivers.  The NVIDIA X Server Settings tells me

```
You do not appear to be using the NVIDIA X driver.  Please edit your X configuration file (just run `nvidia-xconfig` as root), and restart the X server.
```

If I do this, I am greeted with a 640x480 screen in addition to the above problems (I fixed this particular problem with mv /etc/X11/xorg.config.backup /etc/X11/xorg.config)

The output of ldd $(which glxgears) is

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffc0bff000)
libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/nvidia-current/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f6e0f10d000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f6e0ee13000)
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f6e0eade000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f6e0e721000)
libnvidia-tls.so.302.17 => /usr/lib/nvidia-current/tls/libnvidia-tls.so.302.17 (0x00007f6e0e51e000)
libnvidia-glcore.so.302.17 => /usr/lib/nvidia-current/libnvidia-glcore.so.302.17 (0x00007f6e0c16c000)
libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f6e0bf5b000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f6e0bd57000)
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f6e0bb38000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f6e0f448000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f6e0b935000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f6e0b72f000)
```

Comment: run `ldd $(which glxgears)` and check if glxgears is properly linked and what OpenGL library is using. You can also run `sudo apt-get update --fix-missing && sudo apt-get upgrade -y && sudo apt-get install -f` to check for possible problems with your local apt manager.

Comment: I've added the output of ldd $(which glxgears)  There doesn't seem to be any problems with apt-get...

Comment: ok, so the executable seems to be properly linked, let's go with the drivers. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-settings/+bug/523108/comments/3 follow those steps.

Comment: Ok, on step 3 I get an error `update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for gl_conf.`

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/17068/72589 try the section about "switching to Nvidia"

Comment: Ok, that script gives me this:`stop: Unknown job: gdm
ERROR: Module nouveau does not exist in /proc/modules
ERROR: Module ttm does not exist in /proc/modules
ERROR: Module drm_kms_helper is in use by i915
ERROR: Module drm is in use by i915,drm_kms_helper
sed: can't read /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia-nouveau.conf: No such file or directory
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for gl_conf.
cp: cannot stat `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.nvidia': No such file or directory
start: Unknown job: gdm`

Comment: start from this command `update-alternatives --set gl_conf /usr/lib/nvidia-current/ld.so.conf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a hybrid Intel/Nvidia graphics system. I believe that this should work to get your Intel graphics running.

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

To get your Nvidia graphics working, see this link: [Switchable laptop graphics issues on Ubuntu 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160242/switchable-laptop-graphics-issues-on-ubuntu-12-04/160310)

Comment: No problem man. I had this same issue myself and it sucked. lol