# Easy Nvidia to Nouveau switching

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, nouveau

Recently installed the latest NVidia drivers (340), and the tearing, even while scrolling is unworkable. So, after trying various fixes with no avail, Iv'e decided to try and swicth back and forth between the propietary (CUDA use) and open source drivers (daily use), and hence the question:

**How can one easily switch back and forth between the two drivers?**

Just deactivating the Nvidia driver in the "addiontal drivers" menu, leads to "low graphics mode", and it seems like the nouveau divers are blacklisted in two files located in `/etc/modprobe.d/`.

Is there an easy way of switching back and forth, or do I need to start messing with X internals every time?

Comment: Maybe this is what you want: https://askubuntu.com/questions/16998/switch-between-nvidia-current-and-nouveau-without-a-reboot?rq=1