# Installing nvidia graphics drivers without rebooting

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, nouveau

I would like to know if I can install `nvidia` graphics drivers on a system running `Ubuntu 16.0.4 LTS` without rebooting.

I have this requirement created that I should be able to:

```
1) Install nvidia graphics drivers, say version X, on Ubuntu machine.
   Ubuntu, by default, come with nouveau driver. 
   So this step should uninstall nouveau and install nvidia driver version X

2) Uninstall nvidia driver version X and install nvidia version Y.
```

Basically, I would like to switch between graphics drivers(uninstall/install) without rebooting the system.

I would like to know if someone has tried this. Or got any idea how to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure but part of the solution would likely be `modprobe` command to load kernel modules (drivers).

Comment: same question but old answers https://askubuntu.com/questions/16998/switch-between-nvidia-current-and-nouveau-without-a-reboot

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS:

```
sudo modprobe nvidia
```

after I'd installed the drivers with

```
sudo apt install -y ubuntu-drivers-common && sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```