# Easy way to switch between Nouveau and Nvidia proprietary driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, nouveau

I have a laptop with an NVidia GPU, installed along  the default Intel Graphics card. Wishing to get the best performance for gaming, I switched to the proprietary NVidia drivers. However, having to manually switch between Nvidia and Intel GPU, just for example to play a game, is a boring task, and also commits me into closing all the work I have in progress just to make a small break to play a game. Also, running on the Nvidia driver means using only the Nvidia GPU,even for common desktop jobs, raising power consumption and heat by far.

I am not that much of a hardcore gamer. The games I play are not particularly heavy, nor am I interested in having the graphics at full - if it plays it's fine for me. The only reason I would really want to use the full capabilities of Nvidia, is in the case of a heavy game that Nouveau cannot handle properly, or whenever I would want to write and execute CUDA code.

So, I would like to use Nouveau most of the time, but I would also like to have the proprietary Nvidia driver handy whenever the need arises. Therefore, what I want in essence is to be able to switch between Nouveau and Nvidia driver whenever I wish - having to reboot or logout should not be a problem here, as needing to switch to proprietary would mean I aim at a particular task - ,but without having to uninstall and reinstall-redownload the Nvidia driver every time that happens. Any solutions on that?

Comment: Personally I would either dual-boot my customized gaming/work environments or utilize a separate system for each of these disparate requirements.

Comment: Does this help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/16998/switch-between-nvidia-current-and-nouveau-without-a-reboot

Comment: @student It's about switching on the fly, so I guess it should work for me too,that I don't care about that fast of a switch.

Comment: @NoobDoob did you get the linked scripts to work for you?

Comment: I don't remember such a thing. Maybe they didn't work, maybe I did not try at all. I'm tired of the Optimus nonsense to be frank. Nvidia only with no switching is the simplest method. Also staying away from Nvidia laptops.