# kubuntu 19.10 current way to switch between nvidia (RTX 2060) and intel gpu

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu, intel-graphics, nvidia-optimus, nouveau

What is the current (preferred) (year 2020 - Kubuntu 19.10) way to switch between nvidia (RTX 2060) GPU and iGPU (Intel UHD Graphics 630)?

i am interessted in both:
- nvidia with official drivers (version >=440.64)
- nvidia with nouveau

and iam also not sure if it is possible to do this live (without reboot / relogin)?!

the posts  & questions i found about Optimus and related things are mostly predating 2016...

[nouveau.freedesktop wiki page for Optimus](https://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/Optimus/) was last edited 2015-01-09
and if i try to follow the infos i find very varying outputs - and don't know if my command results are just wrong because i have missed something or because it is just outdated / has changed in the meantime...

so it is hard to know where to start...

hopefully anybody has a good idea on this or and links to uptodate information ;-)

really nice would be if someone has a system setup that allows for 'live' switching between nouveau and nvidia drivers..
(there was a [unanswered question in this direction](https://askubuntu.com/questions/855451/easy-way-to-switch-between-nouveau-and-nvidia-proprietary-driver) from 2016 and a [answered one](http://Switch%20between%20nvidia-current%20and%20nouveau%20without%20a%20reboot?) from 2010)

Comment: seems for the nvidia-driver it is possible after setting `PRIME Profile` to `NVIDIA On-Demand`.  

see [How NVIDIA On-Demand option works in NVIDIA X Server Settings?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1201072/how-nvidia-on-demand-option-works-in-nvidia-x-server-settings/1222251#1222251)
at least for application switching (don't know if powering is done automatically..)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use nvidia drivers and on demand feature, xorg needs some patches that are only available for 18.04 and 19.04 [here](https://launchpad.net/~aplattner/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/) I tried that feature in ubuntu 19.10 without success. You can read all information [here](https://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/440.82/README/primerenderoffload.html)

first you need to remove intel drivers to use software based rendering (modeseting aka llvmpipe renderer). Install latest drivers from this [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) and finally, compile/install patched xorg.

The easiest solution today is upgrade to ubuntu 20.04. I explicitly configure the iGPU and dGPU devices in xorg.conf and get nvidia on-demand working very easily:

```
$ offload-glx glxinfo | grep "OpenGL renderer"
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce 940M/PCIe/SSE2


$ glxinfo | grep "OpenGL renderer"
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa Intel(R) HD Graphics 5500 (BDW GT2)
```

offload_glx comes from mate-prime-select and is an alias of:

__NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia glxgears